# Plain javascript ScrollTop is not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

When I get a new message or send a new message chat should scroll down. I handle that with this watcher (I update random value in Vuex and watch for changes within component for chat):

```
watch: {
    scrollChatDown: function (val) {
        if (this.$refs.chat !== undefined) {
          this.$refs.chat.scrollTop = 9999999999999999999999
          console.log('WORKING!')
        }
    }
}
```

I get this `console.log` in Mozilla but `scrollTop` is not working, is there any other solution for this? :D

Comment: To what element is the `chat` reference assigned? Is it a standard DOM element (e.g. a `<div>`) or is it a vue component? If the latter, you have to use `this.$refs.chat.$el.scrollTop`

Comment: I found the answer :D Seems like it doesnt work if the number for scrolling down is too big, when I tried with 999 it worked...

Answer (score 0):

See this one, uses the current height to scroll down

```
watch: {
    scrollChatDown: function (val) {
      if (this.$refs.chat !== undefined) {
        this.$refs.chat.scrollTop = this.$refs.chat.scrollHeight
        console.log('WORKING!')
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: \How do you think, window scroll is same as div scroll ? :D

Comment: I found the answer :D Seems like it doesnt work if the number for scrolling down is too big, when I tried with 999 it worked..

Comment: Oh, I see, in that case, is better if you scroll to the scrollHeight of the viewer

Comment: What if viewer is so long like 100 000 lines of chat ? :D

Comment: @Learner I edited my answer, see the scrollHeight use

Comment: I knew that myself, what if scrollHeight is 9999999999999 ?

Comment: @Learner Aditional, if you think in 100 000 lines, you need to lazy load the chat, only show the last 100 for example, if the user scrolls up, you load another 100, if the user reaches 1000 scrolling up, you need to start hiding the most recent, like the messenger, you no need to load all the chat once, you can load/unload the necessary information, like pagination.